# How to Get sum with percent/100

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mydatabase this table like this

```
id user num percent
1 user1 10 50%
2 user1 30 25%
3 user1 100 40%
```

and i want get result like this

```
username user1
num 10* (50/100) + 30 * (25/100) + 100 * (40/100)
```

this is my query

```
select SUM(num * (percent/100)) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY user
```

but i known this is not right

Comment: What about it do you know is not right?

Comment: @ScottHunter my query

Comment: What *about* the query do you know is not right?

Comment: select SUM(num * (percent/100)) FROM table GROUP BY user

Comment: It looks right to me.

Comment: That doesn't help. What is the expected results of the query for your made up table? What did you get as a result? What are the datatypes of `num` and `percent` in your table.

Comment: I get `52.5` here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/deee78/2. That's what `10* (50/100) + 30 * (25/100) + 100 * (40/100)` calculates to.

Comment: thanks for all now i solve my problem query is not wrong sorry